# Unable to send attachments with Zend Framework to Gmail and Lotus Notes

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to send a file via Zend Framework's (1.10.7) Mail library.

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setSubject('Test');
$mail->setFrom('hello@ex.com');
$mail->setBodyText ( "" );

$at = $mail->createAttachment($txtFile->toString(), 
                                'text/plain', 
                                Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT, 
                                Zend_Mime::ENCODING_8BIT);
$mail->addTo ( "hi@you.com" );                              
$mail->send();
```

The file is a simple text file.
It works with Outllok, I receive a proper attachment but not with Gmail and Lotus Notes.

With Gmail I have this message :

*This is a message in Mime Format.  If you see this, your mail reader does not support this format.*

Lotus Notes says this :

*MIME content for this item is stored in attchment $RFC822.eml. Parsing MIME content failed: Incorrect format in MIME data..*

What's wrong with Zend's Mail attachments ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was our anti-spam software that was messing with the email's headers (in output).

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.attachments.html) say that the first parameter should be a binary string of data that is being sent.

Some of the comments suggest using `file_get_contents()` for sending an image, this of course does return a string, but it is a string of binary data that represent the image.

What does your `toString()` method return for the `$txtFile`? A simple string like

```
return "This is some plain text";
```

or does it return binary data?

You might want to try creating a plain text file with some content, then using `file_get_contents()` on that file and using the return value as the first parameter for sending the attachment, rather than just sending it a plain string.

Hope that helps.

Comment: $txtFile->toString() returns a string and it works with Outlook. I have a file attached in Outlook.

Comment: Regardless, have you tried my method of file_get_contents? Outlook is Microsoft which makes it a special case, which makes it a bad test/benchmark. Remember a smilie in Outlook is a J on all other mail clients. With that of behaviour you could send it anything and it might accept/render it!

Comment: I have the same results with file_get_contents